# display checkmark accessory type when clicking within textfield in tableview cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a `textfield` within a `tableviewcell`. I want to be able to display a `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark` on clicking within the textfield. How do i do that ? Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have text fields in all the table rows? Do you want to show check mark only in the text field that you are currently editing?

Comment: i have a textfield in the tableviewcell. I had wanted to show a checkmark in only the text field that i am currently editing.

Answer (score 2):

```
- (void)configureCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"key"] description];

    if ([self.selectedCellValue isEqualToString:[[managedObject valueForKey:@"key"] description]]) {

        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
}
```

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *managedObject = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    self.selectedCellValue = [[managedObject valueForKey:@"key"] description];

    [self.myTableView reloadData];

}
```

If you are using Core Data then go with fetchedresulcontroller. Otherwise use your array in place of that.

Answer (score 0):

use the

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
//get the cell and change its accessory type to check mark 
}
```